# Measure in powerbi to distinct count number client with a total spend withing the context > zero

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I am very new with power BI and I need dynamically calculate with DAX the distinct count of client that have spend in the analyzed period more than zero.
In the example below if in the report I have the store I expect zero client for store A and 1 for store B. I am not able to have the total spend in the table because this changes depending on what I have in the report. Any recommendation?

| Client | USD | Store |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 50411542 | 1000 | A |
| 50411542 | 500 | A |
| 50411542 | -2000 | A |
| 50411542 | 1000 | B |

Answer (score 0):

Try something similar to:

```
Client count above 0 = 
  SUMX(
    DISTINCT('YourTable'[Client]),
    IF(SUM('YourTable'[USD]) > 0, 1)
  )
```